# Is there a way to turn hair particle into animated, keyframed mesh?

Tags: animation, particles, keyframes, hair

Trying to camera project on a particle system instancing an object, I dont want to change that single object material, because I have painted them differently for each one, Will be good to project by camera, but i am not sure if i can do that. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.